# Text File with Fixed Width

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm trying to transform a TXT file in a CSV in C#. I know only the basics of C#. I read a little bit about the subject and I found here on Stack Overflow that I can do that with FileHelpers.

My source txt file is with this format:

```
14863           0001 t0001991.jpg    p0001991.jpg    0007 ALFA ROMEO Sprint (1985 - 1989) Sprint V14010120309  
14864           0001 t0001991.jpg    p0001991.jpg    0007 ALFA ROMEO Sprint (1985 - 1989) Sprint V14010120310  
14865           0001 t0001991.jpg    p0001991.jpg    0007 ALFA ROMEO Sprint (1985 - 1989) Sprint V14010120305
```

I built a Class like This:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;

namespace ConvertTXT
{
    [FixedLengthRecord()]

    public class ptMedia
    {
        [FieldFixedLength(5)]
        //[FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public int id1;

        [FieldFixedLength(4)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public String id2;

        [FieldFixedLength(12)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string file1;

        [FieldFixedLength(12)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string file2;

        [FieldFixedLength(4)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public int id3;

        [FieldFixedLength(40)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string brand;

        [FieldFixedLength(12)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public int id4;



    }
}
```

And for my main class I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;

namespace ConvertTXT
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = new FixedFileEngine<ptMedia>();
            ptMedia[] result = engine.ReadFile("h:\\PT-media.txt");

            foreach (var detail in result)
                Console.WriteLine("ID1: {0}, ID2: {1}, File1: {2}, File2: {3}, ID3: {4}, Veiculo: {5}, ID4: {6}",detail.id1, detail.id2, detail.file1, detail.file2, detail.id3, detail.brand, detail.id4);
                Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

but Every time I try to run my code I receive an error:

> Additional information: Line: 1 Column: 37. Not value found for the
>   value type field: 'id3' Class: 'ptMedia'.  You must use the
>   [FieldNullValue] attribute because this is a value type and can't be
>   null or use a Nullable Type instead of the current type.

Comment: Is your information in your text file of the correct length?

Answer (score 1):

I Just increased the Fields size counting the blank spaces too and it works now. Thanks for all your help guys.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;

namespace ConvertTXT
{
    [FixedLengthRecord()]

    public class ptMedia
    {
        [FieldFixedLength(16)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
        public int id1;

        [FieldFixedLength(5)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
        public String id2;

        [FieldFixedLength(16)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
        public string file1;

        [FieldFixedLength(16)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
        public string file2;

        [FieldFixedLength(5)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
        public int? id3;

        [FieldFixedLength(40)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
        public string brand;

        [FieldFixedLength(13)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
        public string id4;
```

Answer (score 0):

try public int? id3; instead of this public int id3;

Comment: Now I have a problem in other field. Seems like it's counting the spaces too.  Additional information: The string '1985 - 1989) Sprint V14010120309  ' (length 34) at line 1 has more chars than the defined for the last field id4 (12).You can use the [FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowMoreChars)] to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I added you class fields lengths I get 89 characters. When I add the length in your text file I get 109 characters. So according to your text file you DO get an empty space for id3. Id3 is at character 33 according to your class file. Translate this onto your text file character 33 starts directly after "t0001991.jpg". Basically you should cater for your spaces.